# How can I obtain different metrics on train and val set?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I would like to estimate different sets of metrics on train and validation set in keras. Namely, I want to be able to estimate AUC on validation set but not on the train set. **I see that there is a way to predict labels within my own callback**, but as to my understanding there is already one evaluation per validation cycle for the loss and metrics provided in `model.compile(..., metrics=[])`, and my validation set is not that small, **I want to avoid running score prediction twice**.

Is there way to do one of following:

1. request keras to evaluate a specific metric on val set only
2. trick the keras by returning None before evaluation on the train
   set using any phase flag
3. retrieve pre-evaluated probability scores on the validation set
   from within a callback function

or any other tricks?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
class CustomLossHistory(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, loss, validation_set):
        self.loss = loss
        self.validation_set = validation_set # validation_set = x, y

    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.losses = []

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        current_loss_val = loss(self.validation[1], 
            self.model.predict(validation[0])
        self.losses.append(current_loss_value) 
        # You could also print it out here.

auc_callback = CustomLossHistory(sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score, val_set)
model.fit(...., callbacks=[auc_callback])

aucs = auc_callback.losses
```

Comment: Though it generally solves the problem of getting AUC, it does not answer the question I raise: can we save evaluation time, as I am 100% sure that `predict` or generator equivalent has been already computed on the validation set while it records losses provided in `loss` list within `compile()`. Can we avoid running it twice?